# Type hinting function with two use cases

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

I am trying to fully type hint a function that ensures that an element is in a given dictionary, and then checks that the element type is what the user expects it to be. My initial implementation works correctly, and is shown below

```py
T = TypeVar("T")

def check_and_validate_element_in_dict(
    element_name: str, dictionary: Dict[str, Any], element_type: Type[T]
) -> T:
    assert element_name in dictionary
    element = dictionary[element_name]
    assert isinstance(element, element_type)
    return element
```

it allows me to replace this

```py
assert "key1" in _dict
key1 = _dict["key1"]
assert isinstance(key1, type1)

assert "key2" in _dict
key2 = _dict["key2"]
assert isinstance(key2, type2)
```

with this

```py
key1 = check_and_validate_element_in_dict("key1", _dict, type1)
key2 = check_and_validate_element_in_dict("key2", _dict, type2)
```

now, this only works if the element type to test is only one, like `int`, `str`, etc.
I also want to be able to test multuple different types in my function, like

```py
isinstance(element, (int, dict))
isinstance(element, (float, type(None)))
```

the issue here is type hinting the function in order to make it understand that if `element_type` is a single value `T`, the return value is `T`, but if element_type is one of e.g. two types `T` and `U`, the return value will be either `T` or `U`.

I guess it is possible, but since I'm still a newbie in the type hinting area I'll need some help!

Edit:

I tried making the function support either a single type or a tuple of two different types as base case, so I updated `element_type` to be

```py
element_type: Union[Type[T], Tuple[Type[T], Type[T]]]
```

now the `return element` statement gets flagged by `mypy` with the error:

```py
Returning Any from function declared to return "T"
```

this also raises a question: do I need to indicate each different input type as a new `TypeVar`? In such case, the `element_type` definition becomes

```py
# using U = TypeVar("U")
def ...(..., element_type: Union[Type[T], Tuple[Type[T], Type[U]]]) -> Union[T, U]:
```

In this case the issues keeps being

```py
Returning Any from function declared to return "T"
```

Comment: The first thing to try is `element_type: Type[T] | Tuple[Type[T]]` - what happens when you do that?

Comment: @kaya3 what do you mean exactly for `Type[T] | Tuple[Type[T]]`? Especially `|`, but also `Tuple[Type[T]]` indicates a tuple with a single type in it

Comment: @HitLuca -- The `|` operator was added in Python 3.10 to enable simpler annotations for `typing.Union`. `int | float` in Python 3.10 is the same as `Union[int, float]` in earlier versions.

On the `tuple` point, I agree -- I don't think this is a perfect solution.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `Tuple[Type[T], ...]` which should mean a tuple of arbitrarily many elements.

Comment: Oh I didn't know about the `|` operation, I am using python3.7 sorry. I actually didn't also know you could use ellipsis in stuff like `Tuple[Type[T], ...]`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `typing.overload`, which allows you to register multiple different signatures for one function. A function decorated with `@overload` is ignored by python at runtime, so you can leave the body of these functions empty by just putting an ellipsis `...` in the body. These implementations are just for the type-checker — you have to make sure that there is at least one "true" implementation of the function that is not decorated with overload.

```
from typing import TypeVar, overload, Any, Union, Dict, Type, Tuple

t0 = TypeVar('t0')
t1 = TypeVar('t1')


@overload
def check_and_validate_element_in_dict(
        element_name: str,
        dictionary: Dict[str, Any],
        element_type: Type[t0]
) -> t0:
    """
    Signature of the function if exactly one type
    is supplied to argument element_type
    """
    ...


@overload
def check_and_validate_element_in_dict(
        element_name: str,
        dictionary: Dict[str, Any],
        element_type: Tuple[Type[t0], Type[t1]]
) -> Union[t0, t1]:
    """
    Signature of the function if a tuple of exactly two types
    is supplied to argument element_type
    """     
    ...


def check_and_validate_element_in_dict(
        element_name: str,
        dictionary: Dict[str, Any],
        element_type: Any
) -> Any:
    """Concrete implementation of the function"""
    
    assert element_name in dictionary
    element = dictionary[element_name]
    assert isinstance(element, element_type)
    return element
```

This feels like a deeply imperfect solution, however, as it doesn't provide a solution for a tuple of arbitrary length being passed to your `element_type` argument. It only works if you know the length of your tuple will be one of (for example) 2, 3 or 4 -- you can then provide an overloaded implementation for each of those situations. Would definitely be interested if anybody can think of a better solution.

Comment: I had the suspicion there was something like this! I read about it some years ago but didn't know how look for it, definitely what I was looking for (and you helped me out for the second day in a row looks like, I guess I'll need to hire you as a personal type hinting mentor!)

Comment: I can agree it's not the best way to do it, but I guess I can use it since for now I have at most 3 different type checks to do

Comment: Ah that's great -- once again, glad I could help!